# Creating new columns based on a group-by

Tags: dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame with columns 'post code','item' and count as follows:

| post code | item | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5811AB | res | 27 |
| 5811AC | res | 37 |
| 5811AB | non-res | 5 |
| 5811AC | non-res | 6 |
| 5811AC | mixed | 9 |

I want to make new columns based on the item column groups for each of the postcodes and add the count values. The output should be like below:

| postcode | res | non-res | mixed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5811AC | 37 | 6 | 9 |
| 5811AB | 27 | 5 | 0 |

Comment: checkout `unstack` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Comment: @RaymondKwok thank you that solved my problem.